# Can sometime help to explain the following CFLAGS options?

Tags: gcc

The CFLAGS part that I don't understand is

```
CFLAGS = -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP
```

Can not get answer from gcc --help.

"Options starting with -g, -f, -m, -O, -W, or --param are automatically
passed on to the various sub-processes invoked by gcc.  In order to pass
other options on to these processes the -W options must be used."

Comment: What platform are you using? `man gcc` on linux / bsd is pretty comprehensive; the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) even more so.

Comment: Try `gcc -v --help`.